# Improve Harmonic Mean efficiency in Pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

I'm applying harmonic mean from scipy.stats for aggfunc parameter in Pandas pivot_table but it is much slower than a simple mean by orders of magnitude.

I would like to know if this is excepted behavior or there is a way to turn this calculation more efficient as I need to do this calculation thousands of times.

I need to use harmonic mean but this is taking a huge amount of processing time.

I've tried using harmonic_mean from statistics form Python 3.6 but still the overhead is the same.

Thanks

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statistics

data = pd.DataFrame({'value1':np.random.randint(1000,size=200000),
                     'value2':np.random.randint(24,size=200000),
                     'value3':np.random.rand(200000)+1,
                     'value4':np.random.randint(100000,size=200000)})

%timeit result = pd.pivot_table(data,index='value1',columns='value2',values='value3',aggfunc=hmean)
1.74 s ± 24.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit result = pd.pivot_table(data,index='value1',columns='value2',values='value3',aggfunc=lambda x: statistics.harmonic_mean(list(x)))
1.9 s ± 26.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit result = pd.pivot_table(data,index='value1',columns='value2',values='value3',aggfunc=np.mean)
37.4 ms ± 938 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

#Single run for both functions
%timeit hmean(data.value3[:100])
155 µs ± 3.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit np.mean(data.value3[:100])
138 µs ± 1.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using **multiprocessing.Pool**, the code below has been tested for 20 million records, it is 3 times faster than the original, give it try please, for sure code still needs more improvements to answer your specific question about the slow performance of statistics.harmonic_mean.
note: you can get even better results for records  > 100 M.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statistics
import multiprocessing

data = pd.DataFrame({'value1':np.random.randint(1000,size=20000000),
                     'value2':np.random.randint(24,size=20000000),
                     'value3':np.random.rand(20000000)+1,
                     'value4':np.random.randint(100000,size=20000000)})


def chunk_pivot(data):
    result = pd.pivot_table(data,index='value1',columns='value2',values='value3',aggfunc=lambda x: statistics.harmonic_mean(list(x)))
    return result


DataFrameDict=[]
for i in range(4):
    print(i*250,i*250+250)
    DataFrameDict.append(data[:][data.value1.between(i*250,i*250+249)])

def parallel_pivot(prcsr):
# 6 is a number of processes I've tested
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(prcsr)
    out_df=[]
    for result in p.imap(chunk_pivot, DataFrameDict):
        #print (result)
        out_df.append(result)
    return out_df

start =time.time()
dict_pivot=parallel_pivot(6)
multiprocessing_result=pd.concat(dict_pivot,axis=0)
#singleprocessing_result = pd.pivot_table(data,index='value1',columns='value2',values='value3',aggfunc=lambda x: statistics.harmonic_mean(list(x)))
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```